# Codeception sendPUT type to Input::file

Tags: ajax, testing, laravel, codeception

I'm trying to emulate ajax style uploading of a file in my test.  Is it possible to  use `sendPUT` to send a file and return the response? The controller receives the value via  `Input::file()` -- I cannot seem to access what `sendPUT` sends via `Input::file`.

```
$I->sendPUT('/upload_image', array('file' => 'files.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the function correctly.

Everything is explained in the [official documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#sendPUT):

**sendPUT**

Sends `PUT` request to given uri.

- `param` $url
- `param array` $params
- `param array` $files

The third parameter is what you are looking for. Your code should look like this:

```
$I->sendPUT('/upload_image', array(), array('file' => 'files.jpg'));
```